# Unable to set error_reporting to show errors in a Joomla site. What's going on?

Tags: error-reporting

I am upgrading a Joomla 25 site to J3, and developing a new template. I am working locally on MAMP.

However, whenever any php error occur, Joomla won't show what the error is, instead I am getting the blank screen and making it a real pain to fix those errors and work efficiently.

Whatever I try, I always get the local value of the error_reporting as 0. (Master value is 32767).

I set it in the configuration.php, tried setting via the htaccess, I modified and set it directly in the error handling function inside the includes/framework.php, I ini_set it in the index.php of Joomla and also at the top of the index.php of the template, but yet the local error_reporting value remains 0.

There is no additional php.ini file loaded other than the main php config file and all other local php/joomla sites I have on my MAMP do show php errors according to their specified settings.

What's wrong with this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all common approaches exhausted with no success at changing the local error_reporting value, I started thinking that somewhere in the system's flow there is something that sets the error_reporting to 0, which is overriding anything else.

I did a system find/search for the term "error_reporting" in the root directory of this site.
In my search results, I got a bunch of referenced files.

I started opening them one by one, to investigate. Then finally I came across a system plugin that had the following piece of code inside its main file.

```
// error_reporting set to show all errors except those for notices and coding standards warnings
// error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
// error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);
// error_reporting (E_ALL);
error_reporting (0);
```

I commented out the `error_reporting(0)` and immediately the local error_reporting value became the same as the Master one, and finally I took back the control of being able to show any php errors.

#### Update:

After requests in the comments to publish the plugin name, I checked if the original code included the error_reporting(0). 
I found the same version of the plugin and indeed this code was part of it.
The plugin is **[SEO-GENERATOR v4.6](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/seo-generator)**
* I don't have access to review the latest version of the plugin to see if it is changed on this part.

Comment: what plugin is that? so we can avoid it in the future

Comment: @webchun: Well, because I inherited this site and from what I see, there are many others that have put their hands on it doing all kind of things, I can't be sure if the plugin was developed this way, or someone else did this at some point. It's a SEO system plugin, but before publishing the plugin name, I will search for that plugin version (is about 2 years old) and see if the original code included this and also will try also to check its latest version. If I find the same code, then I will publish its name, otherwise I don't think it will be fair to diminish the plugin and its developer.

Comment: @webchun: I updated my answer including the plugin name.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your **php.ini** file, have a look for the following and make sure the values are set as follows:

```
; display_errors
  Default Value: On


; error_reporting
  Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

Once any changes are made to the **php.ini** file, be sure to restart Apache.

If this doesn't work, it could possible be an issue with the XDebug extensions that comes installed with PHP. Try uninstalling it, and installing a newer version

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting involved (isn't late in UK now?) - I found the cause of the issue. You will fall from the sky when you read what it was. The solution now might seem easy, but it drove me crazy till I end there.

Comment: Was a Sunday bed time answer lol. Wow, I never thought a plugin would do such a thing. Do you know which plugin is?

Comment: Hi @Lodder: it's a SEO system plugin, but for its name see my comment to webchun on my answer below.

Comment: I updated my answer including the plugin name.